# How to connect one digital/analog sensor to two separate devices?

Tags: sensor, dc, plc, split, io-link

I have an ifm electrical pressure sensor witha 3 wire sensor cable which is currently connected to an ifm IO-link master for receiving signals. I want to make a parallel circuit to connect the sensor both to the IO-link master as well as to a PLC. Is it possible to split the sensor cable so that I can get input to both PLC as well as the IO-link master?

I have attached the manual of both the sensor and IO-link manual for your reference.

[image: IO-LINK Master]

[image: Pressure sensor]

Comment: In this case the PLC is the IOL-Master, so you don't need an extra one. That makes no sence. All Prozessdata are inside the PLC and could be used there and/or send to an additional point.

Answer (score 2):

In IO-Link mode this is not possible. IO-Link is a point to point connection and supports only one master.

You can use the analog output OUT 2 to connect that to the PLC and read the analog value there. You need a passive 4 .. 20 mA input for this.

Make sure that the GND is shared between the circuits.